# Mac / Gimp / Background to Transparent for Web

Tags: gimp, png, osx

I have done this before several ways which is why it is very frustrating now.

I read all of [Add transparency to an existing PNG](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6449/add-transparency-to-an-existing-png) but didn't try the "Curves on the Alpha Channel" suggestion from Demis. It's usually enough to (1) Add Alpha Layer and (2) Color to Alpha (2) Export as png or jpg.

I have other images like this one that upload correctly: https://oldcrowhempco.com/shop/green-lotus-hemp-heat-rub/

But then this one I put through the same process, it looks it has trans. backgrounds, but then when uploaded, it's displayed with white background: https://oldcrowhempco.com/shop/green-lotus-premium-hemp-oil-salve-250-mg/

One thing I noticed that I thought was odd when I downloaded the one that's appearing correctly and imported back into GIMP, Mode is Indexed not RGB. However, while I have not been able to capitalize on this knowledge yet, it seems relevant.

Thanks.

Comment: Which images do you mean?  Can you link to the actual image URLs, not just the webpage they are on. Thanks.

Comment: OK

https://i0.wp.com/oldcrowhempco.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/GLH-ECom-Topical-Heat-10.19-547x547-1.png?fit=547%2C547&ssl=1

displays the same as

https://i0.wp.com/oldcrowhempco.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/GLH-ECom-Topical-Heat-10.19-547x547-1.png

but

https://i2.wp.com/oldcrowhempco.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/GLH-ECom-Topical-Salve-10.19-547x547-1.png?fit=547%2C547&ssl=1

displays with white background, unlike

https://i2.wp.com/oldcrowhempco.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/GLH-ECom-Topical-Salve-10.19-547x547-1.png

Comment: Please [edit] your question to upload the images you are having issues with to Stack Exchange's (SE) imgur server, so that the images are independent of third party sites (there's a button above the editor with an image icon). Not uploading them to SE's imgur makes your question become useless once the images change or are no longer available. Also, just linking to pages on your site, not specific images, makes this *feel* a bit like spam for your site, particularly given that your site is in an industry that routinely spams SE (you might not, but we do get a lot of spam for similar products).

Comment: I can't see any obvious differences between these.  The one you say has a white background doesn't have a white background as far as I can see. Sorry.

Comment: It's probably a WordPress issue. I'll ask there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer but too long for comments:

1) I can use `wget` with the URL with parameters to obtain an image which is a color-indexed PNG (60K). But it looks OK (transparent background).

2) Through my Firefox browser, both parameterized and paramater-less URLs are the same 20K image (binary equal) which, despite its name, is a WebP and not a PNG, so there is likely some re-compression going on. This image is also OK in Gimp and in Firefox. However being a WebP it may not be supported adequately with MS browsers. So if you are using Edge this could be part of the problem.

Color-indexed images in Gimp have a "binary" opacity, pixels are either fully opaque or fully transparent. But I don't thing this is what is happening there.