# Why does this PNG image on twitter look different when clicked?

Tags: transparency, png

This morning on twitter there was a tweet with the text "click on this picture". 
When picture is clicked, it's opened in wider viewer, but looks completely different.

I tried to analyze this picture in ACDSee, and I also tried uploading on Facebook, but it's happening only when embedded on twitter.
I don't have much knowledge about graphics so please explain this to me.
Why does this PNG image change only when clicked on Twitter?

Screenshots (left = before clicking; right = after clicking):

[image: Before clicking]
[image: After clicking]

Here's the original [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUEOf.jpg).

Comment: Try dragging the guy in front of the stars, most browsers will then show you that this is a transparent png by rendering it with a gray/white background while dragging

Comment: See also [this answer to another question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9088/image-that-looks-different-on-black-background-and-on-white/9122#9122), where I describe how pictures like this work and how to create them.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The picture doesn't change. The background color of the page does.

It's a transparent PNG. The whites are not visible on a white background. The blacks aren't visible on black background.

The normal post is on white. The modal view is on black.

If you change the background color...

[image: Black]
[image: White]

Comment: Also if you use another background colour, such as dark grey, you can see both images at once.