# Different image depending on background color

Tags: gimp, layers, background, background-removal, blend-modes

I'm trying to replicate [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/9122/141477) in gimp 2.10, but the results are very different. Right in the first step the result deviates.

Subtracting the two images in gimp 2.10:

[image]

And in gimp 2.8:

[image]

In gimp 2.8 the ending results are fine. Why doesn't it work and how can I replicate this in 2.10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in 2.10 you can work in "Perceptual" or "Linear" light, and the standard 2.10 layer blend modes are "Linear" and do not give the same results as the 2.8 ones. You can use the 2.8 "perceptual" blend modes (aka "Legacy" modes) using the switch on the right of the blend mode selector:

[image]