# How to remove a green/blue screen background using Photoshop CS5?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, cs5, background-removal

Using `Photoshop CS5`, i'm trying to fully remove background of a picture being shot behind a `blue screen`. To do this, i am using `Color Range` method (from `Menu > Selection`). It works ok for most parts of the picture but other for some having `transparency` (like hairs), there is still some glowing blue around it.

Here is the original image :

[image]

Here is what i get, using `Color Range`. If i increase the `Fuzziness`, the hairs tends to disappear completely, which is not what i want.

[image]

Here is what I want to achieve :

[image]

Is there other techniques to remove that blue background ? (and thus avoiding the blue glow around the image ?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alpha Transparency Remove Background Photoshop](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13073/alpha-transparency-remove-background-photoshop)

Comment: Also try: [How can I remove the unwanted background from a scanned handwritten signature?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18963/how-can-i-remove-the-unwanted-background-from-a-scanned-handwritten-signature?lq=1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use an `Alpha Channel` to remove backgrounds in images like these.

> This is a rough example, but if you take care to be detail specific, the results will be spot on.

## Step 1

If your image is a background layer, double click the layer and name it whatever.

[image]

## Step 2

Go to the `Channels` panel (`Window > Channels`) and select the layer with a high contrast. I chose the Blue layer in this example.

**Duplicate** this layer by dragging it to the `Create New Channel` icon, or right clicking and select `Duplicate Channel...` You can name this whatever, but this will be your `Alpha Channel`.
[image]

## Step 3

With the new channel selected, go to `Image > Apply Image`. Make sure the blending mode is set to **Multiply** and adjust the opacity to 75 - 100% whatever looks ok.

## Step 4

Break out the brush tool [`B`], select black as your color, and paint the areas that are definitely going to show through at 100% opacity. For instance the fingers, hand and head at the right side of the photo.
[image]

## Step 5

Change your brush `Blending Mode` to **Overlay**, and brush the light & fine hair areas. With Overlay as the mode, you'll be able to darken the fine areas without getting the background too.
[image]

Switch the color to white, to brighten the gray background without affecting the black strokes.

[image]

## Step 6

When you are happy with the masking, `Inverse` the selection (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>) to make the mask white.

[image]

## Step 7

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click to Select the alpha channel mask as a selection. Then go to your layer panel and create the mask.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In Photoshop CS5 they introduced better options for the `Refine Edge Tool` over CS4:

[image]

Awhile back I ran into this issue and saw a very good video in regards to removing backgrounds from hair by Terry White called "[How to Remove a Background from an Image in Photoshop CS5](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adobe-evangelists-terry-white/how-to-remove-a-background-from-an-image-in-photoshop-cs5/)"

Answer (score 1):

As of Photoshop CC 2015.5 they've introduced the `Select and Mask` taskspace, found in the `Select` menu as a replacement to the Refine Edge feature.

It's very similar to refine edge, just with various improvements and overall I find it much more pleasant to work with than its predecessor.

[Here is the official Adobe video tutorial on how to use it.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5vT0lyKSTg)

[image: Screenshot of the new Select and Mask tasksapce]

Comment: This looks like the Refine Mask panel that's existed for a while, only full screen.

Comment: Correct. It's been renamed, and (aside form being full-screen) they added some extra tools on the left and added some transparency sliders for some of the mask modes. I'm unsure if there were any algorithmic improvements. But I do enjoy masking more now than before so I like the changes.