# Is there a trick for removing the background from behind a cage in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I need to remove the background from this image. Is there a trick to removing the background from between/behind the cage part without having to go into each section? The floor, wall and cord will be removed, all else needs to stay. Using the latest version of Photoshop.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/13074/3270 - Same overall premise using color range selection. Or --- https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/22425/3270 using an Alpha channel.