# An issue with adding a background-less image at the top of another image

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've an image whose white background is removed. In particular, I used "Magic Wand Tool" to select and to remove that background (as explained [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18963/how-can-i-remove-the-unwanted-background-from-a-scanned-handwritten-signature) by @Dom) as follows:

[image]

(The white recatngles are not parts of the real scenario, and I've just added them here for the purpose of hiding the majority of the text!)

Then, I just saved the image as a JPEG file, and I added it to another one. What I expected to see was having the background-less image truly without any background placed on another image, but what I get is an unwanted white background as below:

[image]

I guess saving my background-less *.psd file as a JPEG image again adds a white background to my image. Can you please explain how can I save and add my background-less photo not to be disturbed by any (here white!) background?!

Comment: Jpeg does not support alpha channels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just save the background-less photoshop file as a `.png` file instead of `.jpg`. Then, your image will be saved with transparency.