# How do I make a color background transparent?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency

How I can make color transparent in Photoshop?
For example, I have picture of smoke, and I want to make background color (which is black) transparent. How?

Answer (score 0):

A simple technique to use the original image background color/tone to drive the transparency. This works for any color background, providing there is some tonal contrast with the foreground.

1. If you have a solid foreground shape, apply the `Threshold` adjustment layer above the layer. If you have a complex shape like smoke or hair, use the `Contrast` and/or `Hue & Saturation` adjustment layers instead. Adjust the settings on the adjustment layers until it results in a background that is 100% black, while the foreground is 100% white. Any gray or colored areas (we are after the tonal info) will be semi transparent. Note - If you started with a lighter background, add an `Invert` adjustment layer first, as the area you want transparent needs to be black.
2. `ctrl+a` select all of the black and white result and `ctrl+shift+c` to copy merged all, then hide the adjustment layers.
3. Create a layer mask on your original layer and `alt+click` on the layer mask icon in your layers panel. This puts you in direct edit mode for that layer mask. Now `ctrl+v` paste the black and white version of the image in there. Click on the layer icon in the layers palette to escape the layer mask direct edit mode.
4. Smile, you just saved yourself a lot of tracing.

Comment: A note for anyone else who stumbles across this - If you are working with a green screen or any background with a mid tone, you might find it useful to crank up/down the saturation of that color in `Hue & Saturation` first to give you better tonal contrast to play with.